# How to transfer ERC20 token through QR code?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, qr-code, erc20

In Ethereum, we transfer through the following address:

```
ethereum:0x0223acdb0a45622daeb2444e842b5a007a402a44?value=1.01e18
```

But what should be done to transfer the token (eg DAI)? How to set the contract address and other things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ERC-67 standard for payment QR codes never got any traction](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/67). I am not aware of any wallets that would support this features fully.

However you can get a better workflow for mobile payments with the following

- QR code links to a mobile web page
- This mobile web page is a web app
- The mobile web page requests a payment using [WalletConnect protocol](https://docs.walletconnect.com/)
- User will be prompted to 1) connect a wallet and then 1) make a transaction from the mobile wallet of their choice
- Mobile page can fallback to additional payment and installation instructions if the user does not have any wallet installed

Answer (score 1):

From Metamask's documentation page you can see the [Deeplinking](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/mobile-best-practices.html#deeplinking) section. You can embed that URL in QR code.

Live demo: https://metamask.github.io/metamask-deeplinks/

Comment: if Metamask reject **"Transaction gas is to low"**, the only thing you have to do is add `&gas=42000` (for example) at the end of the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your point. I calculate the gas price through the **estimateGas** method